# Capturing key press times for a behavioral biometrics tool using Java or Python?

Tags: java, python, biometrics

I'm trying to create a behavioral biometrics tool that uses keyboard usage patterns to identify the user. The idea is to capture how the user types, but not what. I thought about capturing the time it takes for the user to press and release a key, as well as time from one key press to another. 
I've been looking into [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) but I've only found "keylogger" type of programs and tutorials, same with [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/), which I think it's impossible to use the way I described... 
Can someone give me a hint or tutorial to do such a thing? 
Thank you.

Comment: why do you think it is impossible with `pynput`? Did you try to do it with `pynput`? It can execute one function `on press` and other function `on release` and you can use `time` or `datetime` in both to get current time - when you substract two `datetime` values then you get `timedelta` with values which you expect. I think you could do the same with `jnativehook`. But you have to try to do it.

Comment: Nice Idea, but there is one Important issue regarding the involved environments: The VMs of Java and Python might be not in a real-time like environment to get a reliable and fast enough response and therefore the expected small changes in "presstime" as biometric marker is not robust enough. What we can expect as "immediate" when it comes to a keypress is anything below 80-100ms, from that on the human perception can not recognize any difference, so the driver and its own interrupt is designed around that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pynput` can run one function `on press` and other `on release` and both functions can keep current time in two variables. If you substract them in one function then you should get how long was pressed and if you substract them in other function then you should get how long was released.

In code I check time between any keys and also for every key individually.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import datetime

# --- data ---

press_time = None
release_time = None

keys_press_time = {}
keys_release_time = {}

# --- functions ---

def press(key):
    global press_time

    press_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    if release_time:
        print('how long was released:', press_time - release_time, 'key: ANY')

    # --- individual keys ---

    keys_press_time[key] = press_time

    if key in keys_release_time:
        print('how long was released:', keys_press_time[key] - keys_release_time[key], 'key:', str(key))

def release(key):
    global release_time

    release_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    if press_time:
        print('how long was pressed :', release_time - press_time, 'key: ANY')

    # --- individual keys ---

    keys_release_time[key] = release_time

    if key in keys_press_time:
        print('how long was pressed :', keys_release_time[key] - keys_press_time[key], 'key:', str(key))

# --- main ---

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=press, on_release=release) as listener:
    # ... other code ...
    listener.join()
```

The only problem is when you keep some key longer and system starts repeating key (it generates `release` events) and then it gives shorter times. It would need to turn off "repeating" in system or it would need to more complex code to reduce this problem.

---

**BTW:** I think you could do the same with `jnativehook` in very similar way.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for your help! I can now understand better how listeners work, thank you so much!

Comment: I solved the repeating keys problem using set() to save a key when it was firstly pressed and removed it when it was released, in case someone ever need it.